# hide all divs except one and toggle that one

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='logolink' data-msg='msg01'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='logolink' data-msg='msg02'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='logolink' data-msg='msg03'>lorem ipsum</div>

<div class='msgt' id='msg01'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='msgt' id='msg02'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='msgt' id='msg03'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

`.msgt` are hidden.
What I want, for example if first `logolink` is clicked:
- hide all `msgt` except `msg01`
- if `msg01`is visible - hide it - and vice versa.

**js**

```
$('.logolink').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).data('msg');
    var b = $('#' + a);
    $('.msgt:not(b)').hide();
    b.toggle();
});
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have use `.not` function at this context,

```
$('.logolink').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).data('msg');
    var b = $('#' + a);
    $('.msgt').not(b).hide();
    b.toggle();
});
```

Since `b` is a jquery object and it cannot be passed along a string.

Comment: @bonaca Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.logolink').click(function() {
    var $item = $('#' + $(this).data('msg');
    $item.toggle();
    $item.siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does, how is it different from the original code and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: For starters I combined 1st and 2nd step.(not of great importance, but why initialize an extra variable). 

$item.toggle() same thing as previous.

$item.siblings().hide() would select all siblings (i.e div on same level other than target element)

Comment: That's great, but **edit the answer** (there's an edit link below the post) and put that information there.